# Slow availabilty of Samba

Tags: samba

The other day, I plugged a hard disk (1 TB, ext3 file system) into a USB port of my Asus RT-N56U router. I set up Samba, added two folders, created a user, and set user rights. Afterwards, I copied more than a million files amounting to some 200 GB scattered over many subdirectories. Seemed to work fine, though not very fast.

Now when the device is booted, I can't access that Samba share for a lot of time. The system log reveals that it takes about half an hour (!) to get Samba ready:

```
Jan  1 01:00:17 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk....ready
Jan  1 01:00:17 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan  1 01:00:26 FTP Server: daemon is stoped
Jan  1 01:00:26 Samba Server: smb daemon is stoped
Jan  1 01:01:16 ntp: start NTP update
Sep 19 18:22:52 rc_service: ntp 407:notify_rc restart_upnp
Sep 19 18:40:32 Samba Server: daemon is started
Sep 19 18:46:18 nmbd[502]: [2016/09/19 18:46:18, 0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:become_local_master_stage2(392)
Sep 19 18:46:18 nmbd[502]:   Samba name server RT-N56U is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

After that, file access and transfer speeds are OK.

What's happening here and how can I speed up that process?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the Linux operating system of the device. Normally, all disk IO of Linux is asynchronous (I won't exclude some distros to be less user-unfriendly), and the user is expected to execute a sync before shutdown (or during shutdown, with a sync command executed from the shutdown script).

But there is no such sync command readily available in the router. Whenever I switched it off, there was no marker set on the disk of a clean shutdown, consequently the device run recovery scripts at start up which took so much time.

Worse yet, some data were lost due to missing syncs. Consequently, I do not use that device for samba any more and strongly recommend not to do so.